# Converting a string into float from a strange format

Tags: go

How do I convert a string into a float from an unusual format (e.g. 2.93B, 201k)? Using the normal approach doesn't work i.e:

```
i, err := strconv.ParseFloat("2.93B", 64) // Returns an 'invalid syntax' error
```

Comment: Sounds like a great opportunity for a regular expression...

Comment: does **B** stand for **billion** ?

Comment: Ye, B = billion - I'm thinking regular expressions are the only way to go. Would be a bit of a pain to implement though... was hoping there was a package I could call

Comment: As a hack, you can just string replace the letters with the exponent. So for B, you would do `strings.Replace("2.93B", "B", "e9")`. For "k" you could replace with e3, etc.

Comment: It's a tricky task since **k** stands for **thousand**, as in proper SI unit prefix, while **B** stands for **billion** which is much less well defined English name for SI prefix of **G** and is subject to localisation etc.  It will all depend on how well defined and limited your specific case is.

Comment: @Thebluefish: There are no great opportunities for regular expressions. :P

Comment: We're not here to write your code for you. What have you tried? What approaches have you considered? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: @Flimzy I think if you check the question, I have tried. I'm a self confessed regexp novice so I was asking StackO incase I was missing something from golang.

Comment: @p_mcp: That's an asset. A regexp is a bad solution here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

var siFactors = map[string]float64{
    "":  1e0,
    "k": 1e3,
    "M": 1e6, // Sometimes, M (Roman numeral) for thousands and MM for millions
    "G": 1e9,
    "T": 1e12,
    "P": 1e15,
    "E": 1e18,
    "Z": 1e21,
    "Y": 1e24,
    "K": 1e3, // colloquial synonym for "k"
    "B": 1e9, // colloquial synonym for "G"
}

func parseNumber(s string) (float64, error) {
    f, err := strconv.ParseFloat(s, 64)
    if err == nil {
        return f, nil
    }
    r, size := utf8.DecodeLastRuneInString(s)
    if r == utf8.RuneError {
        return 0, err
    }
    symbol := s[len(s)-size : len(s)]
    factor, ok := siFactors[symbol]
    if !ok {
        return 0, err
    }
    f, e := strconv.ParseFloat(s[:len(s)-len(symbol)], 64)
    if e != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return f * factor, nil
}

func main() {
    for _, s := range []string{"2.93", "2.93k", "2.93M", "2.93G", "2.93B", "2930000000", "2.93X", "G"} {
        n, err := parseNumber(s)
        fmt.Printf("%q\t %g %v\n", s, n, err)
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/DYEe5gQ8pl

Output:

```
"2.93"   2.93 <nil>
"2.93k"  2930 <nil>
"2.93M"  2.93e+06 <nil>
"2.93G"  2.93e+09 <nil>
"2.93B"  2.93e+09 <nil>
"2930000000"     2.93e+09 <nil>
"2.93X"  0 strconv.ParseFloat: parsing "2.93X": invalid syntax
"B"  0 strconv.ParseFloat: parsing "B": invalid syntax
```